# Simple programming language in EBNF form

Tags: compiler-construction, bnf, ebnf

I'm working on a grammar for a very simple programming language and I need to write it in (E)BNF form. I've seen many examples of simple languages where for example only operations are allowed on numbers/identifiers or examples of a larger complexity such as [The Syntax of C in Backus-Naur Form](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm).

What I need (and yes I've searched with Googled quite a bit) is a simpler example that I can take a look at so that I can understand the general hierarchy. Something with variable declarations, function declarations, loops, assignments, operations etc but on a much smaller and simpler scale than all of C written in BNF.

I'm not asking for someone to write one up here since that would be a large job, but if someone could point me towards a resource then I would be very grateful.

I understand the rules for writing a language in BNF; I just don't feel like I have a grasp over where to start and how to order the language.

Comment: What you seem to be asking for is a recommendation for an off-site resource, which makes the question off-topic.  For some simpler languages, consider [`bc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html) and
[`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).  Each has its own idiosyncrasies, but they're definitely simpler than C linguistically.  You could also consider looking for a BNF grammar of Pascal — or perhaps the related languages such as Modula-N (for N in {1, 2, 3})  or Oberon, but not Ada.

Comment: Thanks. The grammar definition for bc was actually helpful!

Comment: Oberon is "Pascal evolved", and is famous for its brevity of syntax.  You can see a complete, working Oberon grammar here: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSParsers.html

Answer (score 2):

(It seems you may have found what you're looking for, but you - as well as future readers - may find the following useful.)

The book [Basics of Compiler Design](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/~torbenm/Basics/) by **Torben Ægidius Mogensen** from the University of Copenhagen contains a very simple language to be used to implement a compiler and an interpreter against. It's BNF is the following:

```
Program --> Funs

Funs --> Fun
Funs --> Fun Funs

Fun --> TypeId ( TypeIds ) = Exp

TypeId --> *int* **id**
TypeId --> *bool* **id**

TypeIds --> TypeId
TypeIds --> TypeId , TypeIds

Exp --> num
Exp --> id
Exp --> Exp + Exp
Exp --> Exp = Exp
Exp --> if Exp then Exp else Exp
Exp --> id ( Exps ) 
Exp --> let id = Exp in Exp

Exps --> Exp 
Exps --> Exp , Exps
```

It's a very small and very easy language to write an interpreter against - you can't go smaller and more pragmatic regarding what you want to do. I recommend both the book, and the exercises it contains.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I have fixed it now.

Comment: This grammar is ambiguous. For instance, Exp --> Exp + Exp can result in both left and right associative addition. It's not a good example to learn parsing off of. The fact that addition (and equality, and a bunch of other semantics here) is unaffected by this ambiguity actually hides the problem with this example, which makes it worse.